# Is there any way to center the title in matplotlib? Python

Tags: python

Hey all I'm trying to plot some dendrograms, but the main title of the figure is shifted to the right for some reason.
Any idea on what I could do to center it?

```
SingleCluster = linkage(matrix1_bnc,'single','cosine')
CompleteCluster = linkage(matrix1_bnc,'complete','cosine')
AverageCluster = linkage(matrix1_bnc,'average','cosine')

plt.figure(figsize=(32,26))
plt.suptitle("Dendrograms with BNC", fontsize="30")
plt.subplot(321)
plt.title("Single Link")
dendrogram(SingleCluster, labels=words1, orientation= 'right', leaf_font_size= "12");
plt.subplot(323)
plt.title("Complete Link")
dendrogram(CompleteCluster, labels=words1, orientation= 'right', leaf_font_size= "12");
plt.subplot(325)
plt.title("Average Link")
dendrogram(AverageCluster, labels=words1, orientation= 'right', leaf_font_size= "12");
```

[image: Title]

Comment: What does Linkage do?

Comment: It honestly looks like it's in the center of the *graph* to me - ever so slightly to the right of the midpoint between 0.3 and 0.4. It's not in the center of the whole image, because of the y-axis labels that push everything off center. Is that what you want?

Comment: It basically creates the cluster. The first one is single link, second one is complete link and third one is average link.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy that is a subtitle. If you look above, you will see the actual title "Dendrograms with BNC"